# Plotting Financial Statements in R

Tags: r

I am trying to load up hisotrical statement data for Bed Bath and Beyond!!! (sorry I always 
Buzz Light year the ending)
So I am using this code by provided on the [systematic investor blog](http://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/)

```
 setInternet2(TRUE)
    con = gzcon(url('http://www.systematicportfolio.com/sit.gz', 'rb'))
    source(con)
    close(con)

    BBBY=fund.data("BBBY", 80, 'annual')
```

the financial statement data in the matrix "BBBY" has labels column labels specifying the line item and the column labels specidying time.

Everytime I try to plot a line item in the matirix, say EBITDA, which is row 21, I get an error or the graph isn't matching the values in the vector

```
plot(BBBY[2,],BBBY[21,],type="l")
```

or

```
plot(BBBY[21,],type="l")
```

Is it the labels throwing off the plotting? What is the best way to plot/extract the line-items in the matrix?

Comment: Wrong data type. Everything is character, so you have to convert. Also, your EBITDA data has commas...

Comment: should I use as.numeric(BBBY)? Everytime I try to plot I get a problem with the NA's, anyway around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Date   <- as.Date(BBBY[2,],format="%Y-%m-%d")
EBITDA <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",BBBY[21,],fixed=T))
plot(Date,EBITDA, type="l")
```

[image]

So, you have to tell R what format your dates are in, using `format="%Y-%m-%d"`, and you have to get rid of the commas before converting to numeric, using `gsub(",","",...,fixed=T)`.